# E-election website

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have the election site in PHP

How can I allow users to access from one browser at the same time

I have used a column in the database when you log on to be 1 and when you log off 0

But if the user has to close the browser the value in the database does not return to 0

Answer (score 0):

Save the ID of the person in the database(sessions). If the person logs out, you remove the ID out of the database. If the ID is still in the database and the person tries to log in on another browser, you just check if the session with the value of the ID of the person exists in the column where you saved the ID in the first place, then dont give them access to any pages and just show a message like:"You're already logged in."

I cant provide you any code since you didn't show what you have right now.

**OFFTOPIC:** I dont know if this is an option for you but you could just make sure a person can only vote one time.